# Unable to get the new paypal SSL CA certificates to be recognized. Handshake to Sandbox failing

Tags: paypal, ssl-certificate, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, windows-server-2012

I am testing a sandbox version of the PayPal IPN system that worked previously, but is now not functioning. The IPN simulator says:

```
"IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information."
```

I reviewed the documentation about the Verisign G5 CA certificate and followed the instructions shown, but the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

Still produces this output: (Truncated)

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 9E01CD86FA9E600EAD505F17E34C0F9BE07E7894E35B20BAF2946F88596BB047

    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 90F662CD0BD319EB87ACFE89CDACEFED2327AC4C827ED74861166B86423B5404
587A70B65BCEA2FAC23F7DDAAA49F9DC
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1445624886
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

I verified that the G3 certificate is no longer in the certificate store, and even removed and reinstalled the new certificate many times. I have spent the last 10 hours on this with no end in sight.

I own my own servers, so there is no other administrator I can turn to... I need to figure out how to solve this myself, and am at my wits end. I know I do not know as much about SSL and certificate chains as I should, but theres no help for that part lol.

Can anyone who has performed this task give me a kick in the right direction, and/or let me know what additional information I can provide to help solicit a solution?

Thank you very much,

Dave

Comment: You may be missing an intermediate cert? When I run that I see 2 levels in the certification chain.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did to import the G5 root cert into openssl:

1. Obtain a G5 root certificate from Verisign (Symantec) [HERE](https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/mpki-for-ssl-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO5624) (get it in PEM format, save the file with .pem extension)
2. Put the file into your openssl base dir (should be like "`/usr/lib/ssl`" on your server, but you may check the base dir by running `openssl version -d`)
3. Run the command to install the cert

   `openssl verify -CApath <ssl-base-dir>certs server-certificate-file`

   (replace `<ssl-base-dir>` with your openssl base dir, and replace `server-certificate-file` with your .pem file, the command would be something like `openssl verify -CApath /usr/lib/ssl/certs G5.pem`)
4. The response would be an `G5.pem: OK` for the installation
5. Try again with the connection command

   `openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts -CApath /usr/lib/ssl/certs/`

   You will see `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` at the end of the response

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the [VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority](https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/VeriSign-Class%203-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem) - G5.pem certificate file into a local directory, and ran the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts 
-CAfile "ssl\VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5.pem"
```

Openssl returned a successful result (truncated):

```
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=PayPal, Inc./OU=PayPal Production/CN=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
issuer=/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3379 bytes and written 344 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1
Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Session-ID: 9E01CD86FA9CEB77AD505F17E34C0B9B8A233BD98E30D705F2946F88596F077D
Session-ID-ctx:
Master-Key: 7AC616B7499ED70B6D75FAD3308C332A48B85987685A514365B7507297A3C6A70CD6E7503CE27A9A157045531B54149F
Key-Arg   : None
PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint: None
Start Time: 1445867355
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Note that I used the -CAfile option to directly reference the CA root certificate.